# Knockout.js & Bootstrap 3 - List Group .active on selection

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

In bootstrap, the standard way of indicating that an item is selected is via the .active class. I have a list group that is created via a `foreach` knockout.js structure.

```
<div class="list-group" data-bind="foreach: people">
     <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-bind="click: $root.personSelected, css: {active: $root.chosenPerson.name == $data.name}">
          <h4 class="list-group-item-heading" data-bind="text: name"></h4>
     </a>
<div>
```

When a person is selected, my call to `personSelected` sets the selected object to a observable `personSelected`. I figured that I could use another data binding of the form `css: {active: $root.chosenPerson.name == $data.name}` to check if the current item was selected, but this does not appear to work. See the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abehnaz/x52VL/)

I think that I might not be using the correct comparison statement, or perhaps there is a better way to do this. Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are on the right track with the `css` binding and combining it with observables.

But first you need to fix your `personSelected` function to correctly set your `chosenPerson` observable (observable are functions you need to call them with the new value as the argument):

```
self.personSelected = function(person){
     self.chosenPerson(person);
}
```

Then I would create a new helper function (you can shovel all this logic into the binding expression but this is not a good practice) which based on the `name` returns whether this person is the selected:

```
self.isSelected = function(name) {
    var selectedperson = self.chosenPerson()
    if(selectedperson) //handle if no person is selected
    {
        return selectedperson.name == name;
    }
}
```

Then you just need to use this function in your binding:

```
<a href="#" class="list-group-item" 
            data-bind="click: $root.personSelected, 
                       css: { active: $parent.isSelected(name) }">
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DQUwD/).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! +1 for JSFiddle & best pratices. Your solution works great. In your helper function, you use the name as the item to compare by. Would it be better to use the object itself? return selectedperson = person

Comment: It is depending on your needs... but you can pass in the whole object with `$parent.isSelected($data)` http://jsfiddle.net/DQUwD/1/

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you weren't setting the value of chosen person observable, you were setting chosen person equal to something new.  Also, when your view model is instantiated, you didn't have a value of chosen person yet defined to test against.

http://jsfiddle.net/x52VL/1/

When you set chosenPerson do this -

```
    self.chosenPerson(person);
```

and test against it like this -

```
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-bind="click: $parent.personSelected, css: {active: $parent.chosenPerson().name == name}">
```

Comment: Good comment on the technical reason why my solution was not working. nemesv's solution may be a better practice solution though